# Do the weaving and do the hovering?

Tags: phrase-meaning, articles

> Do the weaving

> Do the hovering

> Do the drying

I found 'do the cleaning', ' do the vacuuming', 'do the cooking', but also

> Do some writing

> Do a lot of reading

I am confused whether I have to use 'the' or not. Sometimes we use 'the' and sometimes we use other determiners like 'some’, ‘a lot of’, ‘a little’ etc.

Comment: Your question is likely to be closed because it's close to proofreading, provides no context, and shows no research on your part.

Comment: What should I do now?

Comment: @AbuNaimMuhammedKalil - Did you look up the words *weaving*, *hovering*, and *drying*?  What do you think they mean?  Do you understand the word *do* and how it's used?  You have to show us that you did some research, and explain exactly which part is confusing to you.

Comment: I found 'do the cleaning', ' do the vacuuming', 'do the cooking', but 'do some writing', ' do a lot of reading'. I am confused weather I have to use 'the' or not. Sometimes we use 'the' and sometimes we use other determiners like 'some, a lot of, a little etc.

Comment: OK, so the use of the article or a determiner or quantifier is what's confusing you.  That's kind of a general subject, but try reading this and see if it helps: https://www.eurocentres.com/blog/how-do-you-use-determiners-and-quantifiers/

Answer (score 3):

When the verb refers to a well-known, identifiable task or action, we can say

"do **the** {verb}ing":

> I haven't done **the cleaning** yet.
>
> You do the sanding, and I'll do **the painting**.
>
> I will just sit there and smile. You can do **the talking**.

What makes **the talking** an identifiable task is the context: the implicit reference is to a meeting or presentation of some kind.

But we don't typically use "do" with the -ing form if the verb doesn't refer to a known or clearly identifiable task.  For example, what exactly is "*the* hovering"?

Which isn't to say that **the hovering** is impossible. Context always makes a difference.

> The  speed and agility of the new helicopter prototype are much
>   improved. But the hovering still needs work. Team A has been assigned
>   to improving the speed. Which team will do the hovering?